# Substitutions cipher only encodes when message is written in lowercase. How do you make a cipher case insensitive?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, substitution, case-insensitive

```
public static String Encrypt(String plaintext, String code) {   
    
    String encryptedString = "";
    
    char[] alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
            'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
            's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    
    char[] encoded = code.toCharArray();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            if (plaintext.charAt(i) == alphabet[j]) 
            {
                encryptedString += encoded[j];
                break;
            }

            // if there are any special characters
            // add them directly to the string
            if (plaintext.charAt(i) < 'a' || plaintext.charAt(i) > 'z') 
            {
                encryptedString += plaintext.charAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return encryptedString.toUpperCase();
}
```

}

The method above is used to encode a message given by the user, however when the user enters the message in lower case then it is only encoded, if the user entered the message in uppercase then the message is printed without encoding. For example if the message was "IM HUNGRY" then it would print "IM HUNGRY" back but if the message was "im hungry" then it would encode the message. I'm not sure how to make it so that it doesn't matter if i wrote the message in uppercase or lowercase, it should still encode it regardless of the case the message is written in.

Comment: A clue: `char c = Character.toLowerCase(plaintext.charAt(i));`

Comment: What is code in the method signature? Why you don't use the 'alphabet' variable?

Comment: Yo'll get Index of bound exception when trying to use code with length less than 26

Comment: The code is the key which will be used to encode the message

Answer (score 0):

Your `alphabet` is lower case only.  Any character not found in `alphabet` is treated as a special character.  That means all upper case letters, which are not in `alphabet`, are being treated as special characters.

Comment: I've tried to make it both cases so that its not being treated as special characters but it still doesnt work